# I have a issue when I put my windows phone application on background. Id does not allwas return to current state

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing a windows phone 8.0 application. Let's say I'm playing on it, and I decide to leave the app (but not to close it). I can resume on it on two different ways.

1. I hold the back button of the pfone and there will be displayed all the apps that are opened. I'm selecting my app and I resuming on it without any problems, it still has the current state.

2.The problem: I navigate through the menu of the phone and I press on my app. It just opens from the start, and it looses the previous state.

I looked on the apps from store, and they keep the current state regradless the way I'm resuming.

At this point, my app is not in store and I'm using VS 2013 Express if that helps someone who will be kind enough to give me a clue. I looked on the App.cs file to check for a event but no luck so far.

Thank you in advance

Comment: look into `tombstoning` of windows phone apps

Answer (score 0):

In WP 8.0 in scenario 1 your application was suspended and "resumes".
In scenario 2 the application is started again, as if it is not already open.

I recommend carefully describes the [life cycle of applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx)